# Android Test Module (Gradle Plugin 1.3): dependencies from non-default maven repositories

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I'm trying out [APK Tests in Modules](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/studio-features.html#test-module) and went through the whole setup process. It seams that Gradle has problem finding dependencies of an **app** module if they are fetched from repositories other then jCenter.

One of the dependencies is [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) located using jitpack:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

But `plugin: 'com.android.test'` seems to ignore this clause: it's not propagated from `app` module.

Reported error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':test'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':test:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.0.9/MPAndroidChart-v2.0.9.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.0.9/MPAndroidChart-v2.0.9.jar
         file:/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.0.9/MPAndroidChart-v2.0.9.pom
         file:/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.0.9/MPAndroidChart-v2.0.9.jar
         file:/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.0.9/MPAndroidChart-v2.0.9.pom
         file:/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.0.9/MPAndroidChart-v2.0.9.jar
     Required by:
         company-android-app:test:unspecified > company-android-app:app:unspecified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem can be omitted by explicitly adding the repository to the `test` module:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Tested with `buildToolsVersion '23.0.0rc3'` and `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'`

Comment: Its a good idea to put mavenCentral() as the first repo since gradle checks them in order.